# owl carousel scroll to clicked item

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, owl-carousel

I have a simple owl-carousel,

HTML:

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items: 5,
    loop:true,
    nav:true,
    margin: 10
})
```

Included:

- owl.carousel.js
- owl.carousel.min.css

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/93cpX/62/

How to force the carousel scroll to the clicked item?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
    <style>
        .owl-carousel .item {
            height: 80px;
            background: #4DC7A0;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="owl-demo">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {

      var owl = $("#owl-demo");

      owl.owlCarousel({

      items : 5, //10 items above 1000px browser width
      itemsDesktop : [1000,5], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
      itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3], // 3 items betweem 900px and 601px
      itemsTablet: [600,2], //2 items between 600 and 0;
      itemsMobile : false // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option

      });

      // Custom Navigation Events
      $(document).on('click', '.owl-item', function(){
            n = $(this).index();
            console.log(n)
            $('.owl-wrapper').trigger('owl.goTo', n);
      });


    });

</script>



</body>

</html>
```

There are was few trouble with version, and thats why i send you full html page - try it to yourself!

Comment: this does not work... I want to click on an item 5 and that he has moved to the center.

Comment: Oh, sorry, i get it - you have to move manually - let me 5 min and i solve it!

Comment: It's gonna be legen, wait for it, dary!

Comment: @Mario bro!! check it - i cant repeat it in fiddle - but i can repeat in on my localhost!

Comment: @Mario if u want animate scroll - change jumpTo on goTo - first instant, second aniamte!

Comment: Thanks, it is what i want http://jsfiddle.net/93cpX/66/ , but its behaves unpredictably(

Comment: I guess the problem is when use 'loop:true'. In this case indexes of elements are unexpected. Without loop its work fine, thanks!

Comment: @Mario you welcome! about infinity loop - we can add data-index-item - and then get it)

Comment: Please note that this answer is invalid as the plugin has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try next code:

```
var sync2 = jQuery('.sync2').owlCarousel({
                loop:true,
                margin:0,
                nav:false,
                dots:false,
                responsive:{
                    0:{
                        items:4
                    }
                },
                center: false,
                navText: ["",""],
                linked: ".sync1"
            });


          sync2.on('click', '.owl-item', function(event) {
                var target = jQuery(this).index();;
                sync2.owlCarousel('current',target);
            });
```

Comment: In 3 years : D gj anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this one>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
$('button').trigger('to.owl.carousel', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me , I just ended up storing the index of the last clicked item, and executing the following code :

```
//Select by id  if one is set or via  '$("".owl-carousel)'
var $carouselElement = $('#owl_carousel_id')

for(var i =0; i<lastClickedIndex; i++ ){
    $carouselElement.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
}
```

**Please note** : My use case was a little bit different, I have multiple carousels stacked vertically. It would store index and the carousel id when an item was clicked. When the user navigated away and back to the original page, it would auto scroll to the correct carousel and carousel item.**

//Scroll to last selected carousel

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $carouselElement.offset().top},'fast');

 //scroll to last clicked item
 for(var i =0; i<lastClickedIndex; i++ ){
     $carouselElement.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
 }
```