# Angular how to go to Item using NGX Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, owl-carousel

I am using the Angular Owl Carousel package ngx-owl-carousel-o

I am trying to programmatically reveal the next image in the carousel when a visible one is is clicked.

Example: I have 8 total images with 4 of them being visible. If I tap index 3, I would like to move the carousel to reveal index 4.

I have seen the Jquery way of doing this. How would I access the Owl functions when it is a component?
[owl carousel scroll to clicked item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748995/owl-carousel-scroll-to-clicked-item)

Comment: could you provide some code so we can help you, Btw the documentation here [ngx-owl-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel) mentioned that you can use all Jquery triggers using `trigger(action: string, options?: any[])`